# Get the channel list from discord v14

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I need to get the channels list of my guild using discord14 API

On my previous code (discord13) I was able to retrieve them by using this code

```
 const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get(GUILD_ID)
    const channels2 = guild.channels.cache;

    return channels2.map((c) => {
        ...

    })
```

On discord v14 I tried to retrieve them using

```
await c[token].guilds.fetch(GUILD_ID)
```

and I get

```
DiscordAPIError[10003]: Unknown Channel
```

I tried with

```
let guild = await c[token].guilds.fetch(GUILD_ID);
console.log(guild.channels.cache)
```

and I will get

```
Collection(0) [Map] {}
```

Consider that I'm able to retrieve the single channel using

```
const c = await this.getClient(channel.token);
return await c[channel.token].channels.fetch(channel.channelId) as TextChannel;
```

I don't find this part in the Documentation

Comment: the discord.js v13 code works on v14 too, idk what `c[token]` should be

Comment: hello, the collection is empty due "cache" call. with fetch() it works

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this for discordjs v14

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('guildID');

guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
  console.log(`${channel.name} (${channel.type}) - ${channel.id}`);
});
```